# Declaration in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have been given source code by my boss which is written in Vb6, It runs on his machine but it gives an error on mine. The error is about declaration or I could be missing some reference.

this is the line:

> Private WithEvents cP As cPopupMenu
>     the error is user-defined type not defined

Please advise.

Comment: You should provide a more specific error message and the code, or even better a minimal example reproducing the error

Comment: Private WithEvents cP As cPopupMenu                                                      error:User defined-type not defined

Answer (score 2):

Must be because you're missing the class cPopupMenu. Make sure that in your VB project the class cPopupMenu is availlable

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, you are probably missing a reference. The project is probably referencing another activex .dll that hasn't been registered on your computer, and the cPopupMenu class resides there. Have you gone to Projects:References and looked for any references listed as Missing? They will show up there. You can also open the .vbp file in a text editor and look at the references, although going to Projects:References is generally faster and easier. Good luck!

Comment: I dont see any MISSINg reference listed , and I dont see it in the .vbp file in text editor

Comment: You can also get this error message when you are going through ".dll hell", and the .dll is registered, but either the registration is corrupt or an old version is registered. To troubleshoot: Can you go to the object browser and search for cPopupMenu to see if it finds it? If it does, find it in references and note the .dll location. If it is the right version, then you can try unregistering, re-registering. If that doesn't work, unregister and then delete all entries in registry for that .dll and then re-register.

Comment: This is hell...Cant find it there either @Jason

Comment: I don't have much more to suggest, except I did search for your cPopMenu and I found this article: http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/Menus/Popup_Menu_ActiveX_DLL/article.html is that helpful? Also, one last thought, you could look in Project-Components menu as well, although according to the article it looks like it is a reference. Sorry if I wasn't able to help!